# When insing TypeORM and TypeGraphQL, Where do the ({nullable: true}) options go and what's the difference?

Tags: typeorm, typegraphql

I'm working with a server app that uses both TypeORM and Type-GraphQL.

```js
 @Field({ nullable: true })
    @Column({ nullable: true })
    url?: string;
```

When I run GraphQL queries (using Apollo Studio) sometimes the query returns an error for having null values and other times the mutation fails when adding a new value.

I tested multiple variations, but I got inconsistent results will null getting rejected in weird ways. I looked into it found advice from deleting node_modules to dropping the database so I decided I should just figure out what null settings do in each decorator.

What's the difference between putting `{ nullable: true }` in the `@field()` or the `@column()` and shouldn't simply having `?` in the type definition work?

I also have separated my `@InputType()` and `@Entity()` classes into separate files so do I need to use the same values for `@field()` in the input as well?

Full example:

**Entity**

```js
import { Field, ID, ObjectType } from "type-graphql";
import { BaseEntity, Column, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from "typeorm";

@Entity()
@ObjectType()
export class Click extends BaseEntity{
    
    @Field(type => ID)
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
    id: string;

    @Field(type => ID)
    @Column({ nullable: true })
    clickId?: string; 

    @Field({ nullable: true })
    @Column({ nullable: true })
    url?: string; 
}
```

**Input**

```js
import { MaxLength } from "class-validator";
import { Field, ID, InputType } from "type-graphql";
import { Click } from '../entity/Click';

@InputType()
export class ClickInput implements Partial<Click> {

  //omitted the id field because it's generated on the server 
  
  @Field(type => ID)
  clickId: string; 

  @Field({ nullable: true })
  @MaxLength(256)  
  url: string;
```

**Resolver**

```js
import {
  Arg, Mutation,
  Query,
  Resolver
} from "type-graphql";
import { Service } from "typedi";
import { Click } from "../entity/Click";
import { ClickInput } from "../input/ClickInput";
import { ClickService } from "../service/ClickService";

@Service() 
@Resolver(of => Click)
export class ClickResolver {
  constructor(
    // constructor injection of a service
    private readonly clickService: ClickService, 
  ) {}   

  @Query( returns => [Click])
  async clicks() {    
    return this.clickService.list()
  }

  @Query( returns => Click, { nullable: true })  
  async click(@Arg("clickId") clickId: string) {
    return this.clickService.findById(clickId)
  }
  @Mutation( _type => Click )
  async createClick(@Arg("data") data: ClickInput): Promise<Click> {
    return this.clickService.create(data)
  }
  


 }
```

**Service**

```js
import { Service } from "typedi";
import { DeleteResult } from "typeorm";
import { InjectRepository } from "typeorm-typedi-extensions";
import { Click } from "../entity/Click";
import { ClickRepository } from "../repo/ClickRepo";


@Service()
export class ClickService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Click)
    private readonly clickRepository: ClickRepository
  ) {}


  async findById(clickId: string, relations: string[] = []) {
    return this.clickRepository.findOne({
      where: {
        clickId,
      },
      relations: relations,
    });
  }

  async create(params: Partial<Click>): Promise<Click> {
    const u = this.clickRepository.create(params);
    return this.update(u);
  }

  async update(Click: Click): Promise<Click> {
    return this.clickRepository.save(Click);
  }

  async delete(Click: Click): Promise<DeleteResult> {
    return this.clickRepository.delete(Click)
  }

  async list() {
    return this.clickRepository.find()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want a value to be null, you should put it on both.

`{ nullable: true }` in typeorm (`@Entity`) means the database is permitted to store `null` values. Otherwise, you won't be allowed to save a null value in that column in the database.

`{ nullable: true}` in `type-graphql` (`@Field`) means that the schema generated by `TypeGraphQL` will permit that field to be `null`. Otherwise, when querying, you would expect to potentially get an error of `Cannot return null for non-nullable field EntityName.fieldName`.

---

To clarify, the GraphQL schema might look like:

```
type Click {
    id: ID!
    clickId: ID!
    url: String
}
```

Notice how `url` doesn't have a `!` so it's not required, but `clickId` does, so you're going to run into issues if you pass a `null` value.

---

As for your input type, do you want to allow a `null` value for `clickId` to be passed? If so, you would also want it to be `nullable: true` in `ClickInput`. If, for example, you *always* required a `clickId` on creation but made it `null` later, then you could leave that out to require the input for `clickId` to be non-null.

Comment: Couldn't have explained it better myself.  Great answer!